# MySQL: ID that has a pattern (primary key)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a `userid` that has a pattern. Instead of having an ID of 0, 1, 2.. etc, I want it something to be like ADM-001, ADM-002.

What could be the best way to achieve this?

I have absolutely no idea so I can't provide anything.

I am also aware this is not a code writing site, but your suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance. :( :)

Comment: No you don't. You're confusing data storage with data display

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with your PK data itself; that's not the purpose of PKs. You will kill performance and it will be a pain to manage.

Just format it on the client, or in your select query:

```
SELECT ('ADM' + LPAD(id, 3, '0')) formattedId FROM table;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_option]
    [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...

index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string'

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}

algorithm_option:
    ALGORITHM [=] {DEFAULT|INPLACE|COPY}

lock_option:
    LOCK [=] {DEFAULT|NONE|SHARED|EXCLUSIVE}
```

Hope you find your answer here or try [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) site, I am sure you will get your results